# Is this the right firestore rules for app production? any suggestion please

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: my rules]

This below image is my database structure:
[image: my database structure]

Comment: `Is this the right firestore rules for app production?` to do... what ?

Comment: I was using this rule for testing app using firebase, now i want to know if they are good for submitting app to playstore. Is there strong security rules i should do rather than those? according to my database structure

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

Answer (score 2):

If authentication is necessary then use this:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Or else this would be the default:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 2, 11); // example date
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please consider upvoting if you find it helpful.